# PopState not working as expected.

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have on the home page a list of images and on click I fire an AJAX request to load the content to a lightbox. I also have pagination between them. Every time the user clicks on the next or previous arrow I change the URL with PushState and it works well. I have a problem with the back button. Sometimes I need to click twice or more for it to go back. When it doesn't go back it just reloads the same content again.

```
$(document).on("click", ".content a", function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var url = $(this).attr("href");
  $("body").append($overlay);
  history.pushState({}, '', url);
  $.ajax({
      url : url,
      type : 'GET',
      success : function(data){
        $overlay.append(data);
        $overlay.show();
      }
  });
});

$(document).on("click", ".fa-angle-right", function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var url = $(this).parent("a").attr("href");
  history.pushState({}, '', url);
  $.ajax({
      url : url,
      type : 'GET',
      success : function(data){
        $overlay.html(data);
      }
  });
});

$(window).on("popstate", function(event) {
  var url = location.href;
  $.ajax({
      url : url,
      type : 'GET',
      success : function(data){
        $overlay.html(data);
      }
  });
});
```

Comment: Are you ever pushing the same state twice? If you are, or if your event handlers are accidentally causing that, it might explain why you have to tell it to go back twice or more.

Comment: Yes you're right. Every time I close the lightbox and open it again it adds an extra request. I need to see why it does that. Thanks for pointing out the problem.

Comment: Cool. I put it as the answer so that you can mark it as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are most likely pushing the same state twice, probably event handlers firing more than once.

When you debug the cause then you will have solved your case of the misbehaving PopState :)